# How to generate specific tabulations using the Jinja2 module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm trying to generate a C code using jinja2, and have a specific structure that gets repeated. It should resemble something like this :

```c
static t_param const paramRec_time_failure_retry =
{
                                    2605, /* Parameter ID */
              &Params.TIME_FAILURE_RETRY, /* Pointer to parameter value(s) */
                                       4, /* Size in bytes */
                                  0x01E1, /* Security and storage flags */
                                    NULL  /* Application function pointer */
};
```

So what I want is for my lines of code to be all aligned at their end before the beginning of the comments of each line.

Here is my template:

```
static t_param const paramRec_{{ PARAM_NAME | lowercase }} =
{
                                    {{ PARAM_ID }}, /* Parameter ID */
                     &Params.{{ PARAM_NAME }}, /* Pointer to parameter value(s) */
                                      {{ size }}, /* Size in bytes */
                                  {{ ssf }}, /* Security and storage flags */
                                    {% if APPLY_FUNCTION == 'Y'%}&PssApply{{param.PARAM_NAME}}{% else %}NULL{% endif %} /* Application function pointer */
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `format` filter in order to pad your strings.
*Note:* here I am also using the [withespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#whitespace-control) structure in order to wrap the comments on another line to keep the Jinja code from spanning on too much columns

```
static t_param const paramRec_{{ PARAM_NAME | lower }} =
{
{{ '%40s' | format(PARAM_ID) -}}
, /* Parameter ID */
{{ '%40s' | format('&Params.' ~ PARAM_NAME) -}}
, /* Pointer to parameter value(s) */
{{ '%40s' | format(size) -}}
, /* Size in bytes */
{{ '%40s' | format(ssf) -}}
, /* Security and storage flags */
{{ '%40s' | format(
     '&PssApply' ~ param.PARAM_NAME if APPLY_FUNCTION == 'Y' else 'NULL'
) -}}
, /* Application function pointer */
};
```

Which would yield:

```c
static t_param const paramRec_time_failure_retry = 
{ 
                                    2605, /* Parameter ID */ 
              &Params.TIME_FAILURE_RETRY, /* Pointer to parameter value(s) */ 
                                       4, /* Size in bytes */ 
                                     481, /* Security and storage flags */ 
                                    NULL, /* Application function pointer */ 
};
```